# cron job to open php webpage not working , how to run the php file on cron?

Tags: php, cron

I have a php file that i currently have set to open a few times each week using windows task scheduler , and it works fine. I tried in the past and again today to get a cron job to do this , but its never worked for me.

My php file is targeting some other file directories js files to which it updates.

I will post my php file , just in case there is some error. Again , i open this via task schedule twice a week and it always updates properly.

I have tried various methods to set cron up

```
curl --request GET 'http://test.com/weeklytask.php'

wget -q -O /dev/null "http://test.com/weeklytask.php" > /dev/null 2>&1

lynx -dump "http://test.com/weeklytask.php?code=23456"
```

Here is my weeklytask.php file that i open in URL and it works fine to update my other php files

```
<?php
$year = intval(date("Y"));
//WE MAY BE IN NEW YEAR BUT NOT NEW NFL SEASON THERE REDUCE YEAR BY 1
if (!file_exists($year)) $year = $year - 1;

if (!file_exists($year)) die("Invalid year ".$year);

$dir = $year."/leagues/";

$folder_names = scandir($dir);

echo "<table>";
for ($i=2;$i<count($folder_names);$i++){
    echo "<tr><td>".$folder_names[$i]." History</td><td>".$folder_names[$i]." Players</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td><iframe src='createHistory.php?year=".$year."&league_id=".$folder_names[$i]."&full_history=false'></iframe></td><td><iframe src='createPlayerHistory.php?year=".$year."&league_id=".$folder_names[$i]."&full_history=false'></iframe></td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: How is the task scheduler called? Is the CRON not firing, or not executing what is expected?

Comment: windows task schedule simply opens up the browser and then opens the url . That works fine. The cron is executing , but its not running to allow for the php file to open the iframes to load the external data in order to rewrite new js files.  The webpage needs to stay open until the iframes finish loading.

Comment: While that is a big difference. A browser has JS enabled, command line does not, nor cookies. What do the `js files` do? It also won't run the `iframe` it is just going to pull in the HTML source (which is `<iframe...` not the iframe content). You could parse the HTML for `iframe`s then run `file_get_contents` or something similiar to bring in the content to the PHP.

Comment: "windows task schedule simply opens up the browser and then opens the url . That works fine. The cron is executing , but its not running to allow for the php file to open the iframes to load the external data in order to rewrite new js files." — Then the issue is not that you are using cron (which is, presumably, running the command you gave it successfully) but that curl and wget are not browsers - they just download whatever is at the URL, they don't parse the HTML, load referenced resources, or execute JavaScript.